# Starting a new line below a certain word

Tags: line-spacing

I would like to start a new line directly below a certain word in previous line. For example, let the first line begins by 'Let A denote ...' and I want to have 'B denote ...' for the second line. However I want 'B' to be exactly below 'A'. Is there a technical method of doing this in Latex? If you have any other suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: You can use `\phantom` or the `tabbing` environment, or a `tabular`. It depends on what the ultimate context is.

Comment: The provided answer by @Steven is what I was seeking and it is succinct and to the point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\newcommand\rememberthisspot{%
  \tabto*{0pt}\let\thisspot\TabPrevPos\tabto{\TabPrevPos}}
\begin{document}
Let \rememberthisspot A denote...
\tabto{\thisspot}B denote...\bigskip

Now really I want \rememberthisspot A to denote...
\tabto{\thisspot}B to denote.
\end{document}
```

[image]